# Under what scenarios will an App's localStorage get cleared?

Tags: html5, local-storage

I am developing an Hybrid android app using HTML5 which will work completely offline.

Today morning when I opened the app, I saw that all the data stored in localStorage was cleared.

Under what scenarios can the localStorage get cleared?

Given these scenarios, is it a good idea to use localStorage?

Comment: "is it a good idea to use localStorage?" That depends on what you want to store there. You cannot expect it to be permanent, so design your application to take that into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will look different/appear differently on browsers but with the example of Google Chrome, these are the different ways in which `localStorage` for your application can be erased:

**1. Individually deleting `localStorage` keys in the `Developer Tools` menu:**
[image]

**2. Clearing browser history/cache/cookies/etc.**
[image]

**3. Un-installing the browser itself.**